# Passing Parameters for SqlDataSource from code behind

Tags: asp.net

whats the diffrence btw this two SqlDataSource1?

```
<SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="user"  />

</SelectParameters>

SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("user").DefaultValue = "some value";

SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("@param",user);
```

When i use

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("user").DefaultValue = "some value";
```

it works but 
`SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("@param",user);` doesn't:

Comment: @ninjacoder - you're mixing vb syntax with that of C#, tag your question with either of the language along with the current tag

Answer (score 3):

In the selecting event of the SqlDataSource control pass the value to the to the parameter:

```
 protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
  {
   e.Command.Parameters["@user"].Value="value";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks nuux do i need to add this too
<SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="user"  />

</SelectParameters>

Comment: ofcourse yes, you need it to add to the SqlDataSource control as you did it already I think

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use smth. like this:
**SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@param",user);**

that has some overloads.